# Substring each row of a column in mySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table with a column called menu_name that contains a string like "one|two|three|four|something"

I want to write a one time script that will remove everything after and including the last |

So the final value would be "one|two|three|four"

If there is no | in the cell, i.e "something" then I want to set the string to ""

Thanks!

Thanks to Nanhe Kumar for getting me close, here's the final command:

```
UPDATE reports SET menu_name = SUBSTRING(menu_name,1,POSITION(substring_index(menu_name,'|',-1) IN menu_name)-2)
```

Comment: Basically you want remove last word

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(menu_name,1,POSITION(substring_index(menu_name,'|',-1) IN menu_name)-2) AS menu FROM table_name;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with the [SUBSTRING_INDEX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) function.

```
select substring_index(menu_name, '|', 4) from my_table;
```

To return an empty string in case your delimiter isn't present, you could do a slightly more complicated SELECT:

```
select if (menu_name like '%|%|%|%|%', substring_index(menu_name, '|', 4), '') 
from my_table;
```

Here is a SQLfiddle to demonstrate: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/30e98/2

Comment: I should have mentioned that there can be any number of | in the row, so it could be "one|two" or "one|two|three" etc.

Comment: That makes it much harder. But the real question is, Why do you have a table that violates First Normal Form? You should focus on designing your tables correctly, and then you wouldn't run into problems like this.

Comment: I didn't design this table, I'm just trying to fix some legacy issue.  We are using that field to store a type of flat file structure, where the folders are delimited by pipes.  Unfortunately they put the name of the "file" as the last value.  But we also store the name of the file in one of the columns, so there is no need for it to be in the path.